# With Source Control, when should one get the latest versions in the workflow?

Tags: version-control, workflows

In teams, when should one get the latest versions of the files in source control in an optimal workflow?

For example, should it be right before you commit? Or every morning? Should it be automated?

In my current team we have no guidelines about this, occasionally leading to situations of e.g. people not being able to build, or other problems. I'd like to prevent this.

Comment: as a side note, question as currently presented feels incredibly broad

Comment: If some of the answers to that question answer this question, does that mean its a duplicate? If I ask about the flatness of the earth, and someone answers it in an answer to a question about the size of the moon, are those questions duplicates?

Comment: [see explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773): " the proof is in the answers... Neither the person asking nor the person who lands from Google cares if the question has been asked before: they care if it has been answered..."

Comment: dvcs or cvcs? (it can make a difference)

Comment: @gnat: Fair enough.

Comment: @jk I don't know why there would be a different optimal time to do it for either… So both?

Comment: @Protectorone for dvcs you are free to commit independently of pull/push for cvcs you aren't so must always update + merge/rebase before commit/push. both tend to work better with regular pulls/updates